# how to SET NOCOUNT ON for all queries

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a complex application with many SQL queries. I recently found that `SET NOCOUNT ON` improves the performance and bandwidth of server when count is not needed. Is there a way to set `SET NOCOUNT ON` for all queries without modifying hundreds lines of codes? (using SQL server settigns or programmatically)

my current codes look like this:

```
Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.connectionString="DSN=MYDSN"
con.execute "update members set title='something'"
```

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON` being a performance benefit is a myth: https://sqlperformance.com/2016/02/t-sql-queries/nocount

Comment: IMO, SET NOCOUNT ON can be use inside proc.It is helpful if you are connecting with ADO.NET,it will definitely improve performance. It may not be helpful in other technologies like in your "ADODB.Connection" case.It is certainly not meant for inline query.

Comment: From coding point of view you can check classic asp page life cycle, see if any method fire before con.execute  and you get the string there so that you can inject something in string before execute. Even if you succeed SET NOCOUNT ON is not going to help in classic asp

Comment: The whole point of using `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in a stored procedure with Classic ASP is to avoid ADODB seeing the row count as a separate closed recordset object. This isn’t a stored procedure so won’t make any difference.

Comment: @KumarHarsh could you provide more recent data slowing it does provide a benefit, seeing as I have supplied something to prove otherwise? It would be useful to see, as Aaron Bertrand is a very reliable source.

Comment: @Lankymart, `SET NCOOUNT ON` in ad-hoc queries will also avoid the closed recordset issue with classic ADO when executing a batch of multiple statements.

Comment: @DanGuzman you are correct, just trying to correct some of the miss information that had already been posted.

Comment: @Larnu, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102823/using-nocount-to-improve-procedure-performance

Comment: Thanks @KumarHarsh but i was looking for something with some evidence. I think that, as Aaron discusses, in the paste (when the internet was slower) `SET NO COUNT` did offer some performance, due to network traffic. Now, however, in a real business model internet speeds are far higher and thus the performance is effectively negligible.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set `NOCOUNT ON` globally for all sessions by turning on [bit 512 of user options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-options-server-configuration-option):

```
DECLARE @UserOptions int = (
    SELECT CAST(value_in_use AS int) | 512
    FROM sys.configurations
    WHERE name = 'user options');
EXEC sp_configure 'user options', @UserOptions;
RECONFIGURE;
```

That said, I would be wary of doing so since it will affect all sessions on the server. This may break existing apps and tools that expect the default session setting and have not explicitly specified `SET NOCOUNT OFF`.

There are a number of comments to your question about the purported performance benefits of using `SET NOCOUNT ON`. The performance benefits, or not, will depend much on the client API and how it is used in application code (e.g. server versus client cursors). One should not generalize that `SET NOCOUNT ON` will improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only use it per query: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b94fbed1-7652-4222-9796-806440c7f51f/database-set-nocount-option?forum=sqlkjmanageability